# How to correctly return value from function?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to calculate the seats left in each class by subtracting "Enrollment" from "Capacity" and then printing the result in a separate function. However my open-seats function returns no value unless I use the display function. How can I fix this?

```
    #lang racket
       ( define course-list (cons '("Dept" "Number" "Section" "Class Nbr" "Capacity" "Enrollment")
                                         '(("CMSC" "201" "1" "1052" 100 30)
                                         ("CMSC" "341" "6" "7447" 40 27)
                                         ("CMSC" "341" "3" "7443" "40" 29)
                                         ("CMSC" "331" "5" "7746" 40 36)
                                         ("CMSC" "331" "6" "7747" 40 "40")
                                         ("CMSC" "471" "3" "8196" 40 31))

                                  )
            )

   (define (open-seats section)
      (for ([e (in-list  course-list)])
        (if (equal? section (string->number (list-ref e 2))) (- (list-ref e 4) (list-ref e 5)) 'something)
       ;(if (equal? section (string->number (list-ref e 2))) (display(- (list-ref e 4) (list-ref e 5))) 'something)
            )
        )
  ;test open-seats          
     (open-seats 1)

  (define (report-open-seats list-of-courses)
    (for ([e (in-list course-list)])
      (if (and (number? (list-ref e 4)) (number? (list-ref e 5))) (displayln(string-append (list-ref e 0) (list-ref e 1) " (Section " (list-ref e 2) ")=> " (open-seats 1))) newline)
            )
   )

  ; leave the following function call intact
  ;(report-open-seats course-list)
```

Comment: If you want to return values, avoid `for` loops.

Comment: Forget about other languages you've learned, in particular things like loops and assignment. Learn Scheme like you've never experienced programming before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make up a list of the items you can use [for/list](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) like this:

```
(define (open-seats section)
  (for/list ([e (in-list  course-list)]
             #:when (equal? section (string->number (list-ref e 2))))
    (- (list-ref e 4) (list-ref e 5))))
```